# Java (Android) library project - How to design optional modules?

Tags: java, android, reflection, jar, circular-dependency

I am creating an Android (Java) based library project (JAR) where there are -

1. Core features
2. Optional features

Now due to **size constraints**, I have to break this JAR into collection of JARs, where user of this library will have the flexibility to include optional JARs. At the same time, the requirement is to provide a single interface to the user, using which they should be able to call **both** core and optional APIs.  To achieve this, I have two solutions in mind -

**Solution-1**
Have class implementation for the interface in core library, where APIs related to core feature are implemented here, but API for optional features will be invoked from here using reflection, so that if class found, indicates that optional library is included otherwise not.

*APIInterface.java*

```
public interface APIInterface {
    public void coreMethod();
    public void optionalMethod();
}
```

*CoreClass.java*

```
public class CoreClass implements APIInterface {
  public void coreMethod() {
    // implementation
  }
  public void optionalMethod() {
    // use reflection to access optional method from OptionalClass
  }
}
```

*OptionalClass.java*

```
public class OptionalClass {
  public void optionalMethod() {
    new CoreClass().utilityMethod(); // or super.utilityMethod();
    // implementation
  }
}
```

*Pros* - Here only *optional* includes *core* (for core utility methods), *core* doesn't include *optional*.  So no circular dependency.
*Cons* - Reflection is used

**Solution-2** 
To avoid reflection mentioned in solution-1, create two versions of optional libraries. First with full implementation and second with empty implementation (only wrappers).  Users will have to include mandatorily either one of them, depends on whether user needs optional features or not.  With this, the dependency will be inversed. So, core will include the optional library by default, and will be able to call the API from optional library without reflection.

*APIInterface.java*

```
public interface APIInterface {
    public void coreMethod();
    public void optionalMethod();
}
```

*CoreClass.java*

```
public class CoreClass implements APIInterface {
  public void coreMethod() {
    // implementation
  }
  public void optionalMethod() {
    new OptionalClass().optionalMethod();
  }
}
```

*OptionalClass.java*  // full implementation

```
public class OptionalClass {
  public void optionalMethod() {
    new CoreClass().utilityMethod(); // or super.utilityMethod();
    // optional implementation
  }
}
```

*OptionalClass.java*  // empty implementation

```
public class OptionalClass {
  public void optionalMethod() {
    // do nothing
  }
}
```

*Pros* -
No reflection
*Cons* - 
1. There is a circular dependency on core and optional, since **core** includes **optional** to invoke optional API and **optional** includes **core** to use core utilities and services.
2. User will have to mandatorily include optional JARs (either full or empty implementation)

Which solution you recommend or any other better solution?  Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the bridge pattern. Provide an interface for each optional jar file in the core file and implement the interface in the optional jar.

```
// in the core jar file
public interface Optional {
    void optionalMethod();
}

// in the optional jar file
public class OptionalImpl implements Optional {
    public void optionalMethod() {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

Now, make a Builder for CoreClass, where you can set the implementations accordingly.

```
CoreClass coreClass = new CoreClass.Builder()
    .setOptional(new OptionalImpl())
    .build();
```

In the CoreClass, check whether an implementation is present, and delegate the calls accordingly.

```
public class CoreClass implements APIInterface {
    // is set via Builder
    private Optional optional = null; 

    public void coreMethod() {
        // implementation
    }

    public void optionalMethod() {
        if(optional != null) {
            optional.optionalMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes your solution is correct.  This is what I did before even going for solution1&2.  But here what I am trying to achieve is, user of this library shouldn't go through code changes when optional library is included or not.  So, user need not build the coreClass differently when optional jar is include or not.  All I am trying to avoid is any object creation (here new OptionalImpl()) at user end when optional jar is included.  Also, could you please suggest among Solution 1&2, which one you prefer?  Thanks.

Comment: I would still use my solution, but dynamically check in the Constructor of CoreClass if the Optional class is present, and if it is, create and set the implementation as outlined above. `try { Class optionalClass = Class.forName("my.package.Optional"); optional = (Optional) optionalClass.newInstance(); } catch(Exception ignore) { }`.

Comment: Thanks patloew for your suggestion.  Dynamically checking for optional class using Class.forName is basically reflection as I mentioned in Solution-1.  I am going with this, as I do not see any other suggestion or comments.

Comment: Yes, it uses reflection, but only when creating the class, not each time an optional method is called. Therefore the overhead introduced by reflection is minimized with this solution.